# Retrieve object from custom UITableViewCell on selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

So I have a UITableView populated with custom UITableViewCell. Every cell is loaded with an object i would like to retrieve upon row selection.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
// Here I would like to retrieve the object associated with the selected row.

// Object "cell" is inferred as a UITableViewCell, not as CustomTableViewCell :(
var cell = myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

}
```

As described above, I can't access the CustomTableViewCell in order to get the associated object. Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, your `UITableView` is backed up by a data source, which is e.g. an array. Therefore, use the provided `indexPath` to get the object from the array.

Apart from that, you can also cast the cell to your custom class:

```
var cell = myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast it to `CustomTableViewCell`, try that:

```
var cell = myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to type cast to the **class** which you have used when constructing the `cell`.

```
let cell = myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

or

```
let cell = myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as MyTableViewCellClass
```